# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 only on get request page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

After building my project. I've noticed I am getting this error after building my application. 
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

I am only getting this error message only on pages when I am using a get request.

My server code looks something like this

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
});

app.get('/api/global_rankings', function(request, response){
    pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
        if(err){
            return response.status(400).send(err);
        }
        else{
            db.query("some query", function(err, table){
                done();
                if(err){
                    return response.status(400).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    response.status(201).send({value: table.rows});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Ive noticed if i delete the first get request, my second get request works fine. However, I need the first get request or-else I get an GET error message when page is not refreshed.
source: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

Is there any way I can fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a response, and the first character is `<` which I guarantee is an `<html>` tag because you are getting HTML back and trying to parse it as JSON.

The reason it works if you remove your first request is because `*` matches any request, including `/api/global_rankings` so when you have both methods it matches the `*` and returns an error page.

Switch the method order and see if it does not work like you want then:

```
app.get('/api/global_rankings', function(request, response){
    pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
        if(err){
            return response.status(400).send(err);
        }
        else{
            db.query("some query", function(err, table){
                done();
                if(err){
                    return response.status(400).send(err);
                }
                else{
                    response.status(201).send({value: table.rows});
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the catch-all router `/*` at the end so it executes only if the route isn't `/api/global_rankings`:

```js
app.get('/api/global_rankings', function(request, response) { ... }

app.get('/*', function(req, res) { ... });
```